Commutator relations for Lie brackets

With  $$ X_1 := y \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - 2xy^2
\frac{\partial}{\partial z} \quad \text{and} \quad Y_1 :=
 \frac{\partial}{\partial y},$$ Calculate $[X_1, Y_1]$

Solution
We have the Lie bracket formula:
$$[X,Y]=X(Y(f))-Y(X(f))$$
Calculating: $Y(f)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ and $$X(Y(f))=y \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} - 2xy^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=y \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y} - 2xy^2 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z\partial y},$$
then, with $X(f)=y \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} - 2xy^2 \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ we get that $$Y(X(f))= \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(y \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} - 2xy^2 \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\right)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial y\partial x}fy-4xy\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial z}2xy^2$$
Using the Lie bracket formula:
\begin{equation}
       [X,Y]=y \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y} - 2xy^2 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z\partial y}-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial y\partial x}fy+4xy\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial z}2xy^2
   \end{equation}
In the last equation I placed the y in the 4th term on the right of the operator, shouldn't that yield further simplification of the the derivative, or should that y be on the left of the operator?
Thanks

Why are $X_1,Y_1,Y_2$ carrying indices at the start of your post?

Edit.
Since Dr. Tony Tony Chopper calculated another Lie bracket I had
to get to the bottom of this. In fact one of your equations was
totally wrong. The correct one is
$$\tag1
Y(X(f))= \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(y \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} - 2xy^2 \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\right)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\color{red}{y\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}}-4xy\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial z}2xy^2\,.
$$
Then,
\begin{align}\tag2
\require{cancel}
[X,Y]{\color{red}{(f)}}&=\bcancel{y \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}} -\cancel{2xy^2 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z\partial y}}-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}-\color{red}{\bcancel{y\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}}}+4xy\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}+\cancel{\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial z}2xy^2}\,.
\end{align}
Therefore,
$$\tag3
\boxed{\quad[X,Y]{\color{red}{(f)}}
= 
-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+4xy\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\,
\quad\phantom{\Bigg|}}$$
which is Dr. Chopper's answer that he unfortunately deleted.

Kurt, so you can flip the positions of all functions except $f$ before and after the operator signs and even the operators themselves, ie. $$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y \partial x}=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y} $$ ? . Because some functions would not give an equal results on this equality.

@Superunknown I don't get that. Maths is not symbol flipping. All I know is the product rule, the chain rule and that smooth functions have mixed partials where the order does not matter.

"The order does not matter". Thanks, that answered my question.

@Dr. Tony Tony Chopper, on behalf of the OP I apologize and -speaking with Dr. Erwin Schrödinger-: "I regret that I ever got involved."

does the fact that the order of operation does not matter as you said, only account for Lie derivatives? Because I have checked that  $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x)\ne f(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ . So this statement that the order of mixed partials doesn't matter confuses me a little. Maybe you mean $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial  x\partial y}=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y \partial x }$

I surely meant (as I said) the mixed partials: $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial  x\partial y}=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y \partial x },.$

OK. thanks Kurt!

Recall that the Lie bracket $[X,Y]$ is the unique vector field such that
$$\mathcal L_{[X,Y]} = \mathcal L_X\circ \mathcal L_Y - \mathcal L_Y\circ \mathcal L_X$$
where $\mathcal L_X$ is the Lie derivative along $X$. Now let $f\in C^\infty(M)$ be a smooth function, then
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mathcal L_X\circ \mathcal L_Y(f)&= y\frac{ \partial ^2f}{\partial x\partial y} -2xy^2\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial z\partial y }\\
\mathcal L_Y\circ \mathcal L_X(f)&= \frac{\partial }{\partial y}\left( y\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \right)- \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left( 2xy^2 \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \right) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + y \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y} - 4xy\frac{\partial f}{\partial z }-2xy^2\frac{\partial^2f }{\partial z\partial y}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Observe that we can change order of differentiation because $f$ is smooth. Thus we obtain that
$$\mathcal L_{[X,Y]}(f) = \mathcal L_X\circ \mathcal L_Y(f) - \mathcal L_Y\circ \mathcal L_X(f) = \left(-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+4xy\frac{\partial }{\partial z}\right)(f).$$
Or equivalently,
$$[X,Y] = -\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+4xy\frac{\partial }{\partial z}.$$
Coming back to your question: No you cannot place the $y$ there. Your mistake is the following:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y\partial x} (fy) \neq \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(y\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)=\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial y\partial x}(fy) = y \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}.$$
As a tip, make sure you keep track of what ur taking derivatives off. One can do this by using parentheses.

That minus sign...

Thanks for pointing it out! It should be correct now :)

So there is a sequence for commutation, where $\frac{d}{dx}f\ne f\frac{d}{dx}$?

I dont fully understand what you mean. But the thing you wrote down without writing all the steps was the inequality I have written.
But the operator $\frac{d}{dx}f= f\frac{d}{dx} $ if and only if $f$ is independent of $x$.
